# Generating multiple escript executables in a mix project

Tags: erlang, elixir, elixir-mix

Say I have an Elixir project I want to use to build elixir-backed command line tools for myself. I can create such tools with [escript](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/master/Mix.Tasks.Escript.Build.html).

It seems like it's only possible to create one escript executable per mix project. Even if I do something like this in `mix.exs`:

```
  def project do
    [
      elixir: "~> 1.4",
      deps: deps(),
      # (...)
      escript: escript(:foo),
      escript: escript(:bar),
    ]
  end


  def escript(name) do
    [
      name: name,
      main_module: Some.Module.Name,
    ]
  end
```

Only the first entry from the project keyword list gets taken into account:

```
$ mix escript.build
Compiling 2 files (.ex)
Generated whatever app
Generated escript foo with MIX_ENV=dev
```

What's the best way of generating multiple escript executables from one mix project?

Comment: I checked [the source of escript.build](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/c76708a05e55686f3f597c81a8210df6c3dcb388/lib/mix/lib/mix/tasks/escript.build.ex) and there doesn't seem to be any support for building multiple escripts. I think the Elixir team might be open adding this feature. You could try posting a feature request to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/elixir-lang-core to hear their views.

Comment: Meanwhile you can run `mix escript.build` as many times as you want.

Comment: You could use an umbrella project for something like this.

Comment: @nietaki were you able to solve this? I'm trying to do something similar, it seems an umbrella project could be the way to go.

Comment: @acrogenesis I think I decided against using escript in the end. An umbrella project does sound like a good, clean way of doing it, if a little verbose.